# Put margin between elements in IOS stack view

Tags: ios, uistackview

I want a login screen that contain user name and password text field and a button. I add all this fields in a stack view and the margin between the components gone.How can I put margin between elements in IOS stack view?

Comment: have you refered this, https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views ? @Shanto George

Comment: thank you for you replay,let me check

Comment: you are welcome. Please check it. It will surely help you. @Shanto George

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the stackView and set spacing.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

UIStackView has a property called **Spacing**. you can set this property value as per your spacing need.